# \texttt{} not formatting code as needed

Tags: accents, typewriter

I'm using `\texttt{<template is="dom-repeat" items="array"></template>}` to show a piece of code in my document, however this is not the desired output. It looks like this: [image]

How can I remove the `¨` on top of the i-character?

Comment: you haven't shown any relevant code but I guess you have babel and a language option that makes `"` a shorthand for umlaut. You can turn the shorthand off, or use `\verb` rather than `\texttt`

Comment: I've updated the OP with the code

Comment: Your code works fine in my mwe. Please post a complete mwe so the problem can be better addressed.

Comment: No  the code you have posted can not be run through latex as it is, and if minimally extended to make a small document it would not make an i-umlaut, you should show an example that defines "i to be \"\i (but as I say, assuming that you have used babel, use `\shorthandsoff` or use `\verb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say but I assume you are using an option such as german to make `"` a shorthand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\texttt{<template is="dom-repeat" items="array"></template>}

\verb|<template is="dom-repeat" items="array"></template>|

{\shorthandoff" \texttt{<template is="dom-repeat" items="array"></template>}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm using [english, dutch] package but that could be close to german.

Comment: I got it working now, I'm using the \shorthandoff" command!

Comment: @GaetanoHerman see why the question example should have `\documentclass.... \end{document}` ?  You didn't give that many clues you were using babel at all never mind guessing the language:-)

Comment: Yeah, my bad! Didn't have a lot of experience with LaTeX yet... And didn't have a clue it would be because of the language.